# metaInfo fail Gridsome - typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, gridsome

I would like to use Vuejs with typescript and *gridsome*.

The pluging use for the typescript side is ***gridsome-plugin-typescript***.

here is my `<script>`

```
<script lang='ts'>
  import Vue from "vue"

export default Vue.extend({
  metaInfo: {
      title: 'About us'
  }
})
</script>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ metaInfo: { title: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentOptions<Vue, DefaultData<Vue>, DefaultMethods<Vue>, DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition<Record<string, any>>, Record<...>>'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'metaInfo' does not exist in type 'ComponentOptions<Vue, DefaultData<Vue>, DefaultMethods<Vue>, DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition<Record<string, any>>, Record<...>>'
```

It seems something related with the plugin that does not acept the parameter. But not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I seem I found the right configuration (vue-shims.d.ts):

OLD - BAD config

```
declare module "*.vue" {
  import Vue from "vue";
  export default Vue;
}
declare module "vue/types/options" {
  interface ComponentOptions<V extends Vue> {
    metaInfo?: any;
  }
}
```

The way I realize here was something odd was because inside the dependency:
*node_modules/vue-meta/types/vue.d.ts* was a declaration doing the same thing. Additionally, the *index.d.ts* in the same file *export default and literal-object*.

***Corrected Code:***

```
declare module "*.vue" {
  import * as Vue from "vue";
  export default Vue;
}
```

A you see now the declaration ***import * as Vue*** .

Think the answer is right, but if there's a feedback glad to read it.

Answer (score -1):

check this out this issues! this is help for you:)

[How to use vue-meta in Vue TypeScript's template? · Issue #144 · nuxt/vue-meta](https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta/issues/144#issuecomment-565089983)

Comment: woops, i created minimal sample and tried this code, it's have no error. you and my env has a bit difference maybe. could you try to set up `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json`?  it's works fine in my env too. see: [Typescript compiler fails when using metaInfo\(\) function · Issue \#340 · nuxt/vue\-meta](https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta/issues/340#issuecomment-493383128)